# KIBANA-OPENSEARCH | Not able to create visualisation

Tags: kibana, dsl

I am trying to create a visualisation in kibana through DSL(Domain-Specific language). Below are the required conditions

1. it should match below conditions

   `abc.eventType.keyword:abc-creative-xyz`  and `abc.status:COMPLETE`
2. we have one more property as well i.e. `abc.sourceUrl.keyword` that contains full value of URLs being triggered

   For ex

   ```
   https://s3.amazonaws.com/afsdfsd.sdfs.com/m/243/978723/7987/9898789/ORYEIUR_YOERIEY_ghEWEW_15s_LM_000_YIEY_ER_134343_2342343_143.mp4
   ```

I want to get domain names only like `s3.amazonaws.com` there can be millions of such URLs but domain names are specific

3. Out of found domain name i need to exclude some domain names

For example : `abc.dfdsd.com`

4. Finally we need to display the results in form of pie chart

I have tried many solutions like variety of DSL queries but nothing seems to be working. Kindly note that I cannot change fiels on index since it is prod environment

Any help is appreciated